# Why am am able to load a kernel module when the kernel config says "not set" for that module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a kernel (4.14.136) on target system where netfilter multiport match support is not configured either as builtin or loadable module:

```
$ zgrep MULTIPORT /proc/config.gz
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MULTIPORT is not set
```

Trying to use `multiport` with `iptables` does not work, as is expected:

```
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p udp -m multiport --dports 1111,2222 -j LOG
iptables v1.8.2 (legacy): Couldn't load match `multiport':No such file or directory
```

On a development machine I reconfigured the kernel to have `multiport` support as module, ran `make modules` and copied the new module file `net/netfilter/xt_multiport.ko` to the target machine. I did not reboot the target so the kernel is still the "old" one without `multiport` module configured.

On target, the new `multiport` module loads without problems or errors:

```
$ zgrep MULTIPORT /proc/config.gz
$ CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MULTIPORT is not set
$ insmod /root/xt_multiport.ko
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
xt_multiport            4921
```

I can now add the `iptables` rule that failed previously. The rule now sends entries to `syslog` when I send packets to ports 1111 or 2222, so the `multiport` module seems to be working.

Why is that? I assumed kernel would give you error if you try to load module that is set to "not set" in kernel config.

Comment: .config is used by the kernel at build time, not at runtime. Note that definitions may be used in other places, so your plan will fail in some cases.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. On the first part you didn't compile the module. Kernel try to load the module and find no match module and give you an error. So you have an error. Modules are often independent to main kernel (so the usefulness), so kernel should not known what modules you compiled.

Comment: @stark My question was based on my (wrong) assumption that the kernel could only load modules that were set to `=m` in the kernel `.config`. Hence my confusion why it wasn't so. First I wasn't sure what you meant with our comment but now after reading answer by @MarcoBonelli I understand what you mean.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I thought I had a problem, when in reality everything worked as expected! :D The first error about missing module was expected. It was the latter part about module loading without problems that I was confused about. But it was due to my misunderstanding about kernel .config and module loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a config as not set or set to `=n` does not mean that the kernel will not be able to load the module. It only means that when the kernel was configured and built, that module was not built (otherwise you'd see either `=y` or `=m`). If you get the kernel sources for the appropriate version and configure and build the module yourself, you will still be able to load it in your kernel.

In fact, this is exactly how any external module is added to an existing kernel. For example, when Wireguard was still not merged in kernel sources, installing it required compiling and installing the `wireguard` kernel module too.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking that maybe it is like this, but couldn't think of good search terms that would result in any confirmation either way. I had been under assumption that when a module is configured as `=m`, the kernel is built with a special "attachment point" so that particular module can be loaded at run time.  It is also a big (but pleasant!) surprise that even with kernel configured and built with a module set to `=n`, it is still possible to compile the module later and the kernel will load it.

Comment: @Tomiml I had your exact same question. When building the Kernel, you have 3 options for drivers: **Not Set, Set** and **Kernel Module** (not sure what exact names are). If you set it to **Kernel Module**, what I think it means is that it will compile it, and if you use something like `modprobe` (to add a module) it will load it. If it is set to **Not Set** though, `modprobe` would not work, because it has not been built. But if you build it manually and add it to the right folder (like you did), then it behaves as if it was set to **Kernel Module**. I could be wrong though.